# Error Creating the View in IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-mq

I installed `Eclipse`, `WebSphere Studio IES V3.3`, and finally `WebSphere MQ V7.0.1.3` respectively on Windows 10.

After this complete installation when I open the `IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer` I got this Error:

**Error creating the view.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (149).**

Error Details:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (149).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:605)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:69)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:131)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.tests.Notify.pluginEnabled(Notify.java:96)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.internal.base.NotificationManager.notifyPluginEnabled(NotificationManager.java:869)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.internal.base.UiPlugin.sendPluginEnablementEvents(UiPlugin.java:2464)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.internal.base.UiPlugin.addNavigatorView(UiPlugin.java:1555)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.internal.views.MQNavigatorView.createPartControl(MQNavigatorView.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActivationList.setActive(WorkbenchPage.java:4080)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$17.runWithException(WorkbenchPage.java:3145)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3659)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3296)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$25.runWithException(Workbench.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3659)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3296)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2309)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2219)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$4.run(Workbench.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.rcp.internal.base.RcpApplication.run(RcpApplication.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethod(EclipseAppContainer.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1148)

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:111)
    ... 59 more

Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Incompatible file format. Workspace was saved with an incompatible version: 0.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceTreeReader.getReader(WorkspaceTreeReader.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreTree(SaveManager.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1319)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:1949)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:1713)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:999)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:993)
    ... 64 more
```

**Unsuccessful tricks which I have done:**

1. Delete `variablesAndContainers.dat` from
   `C:\Users\hosein\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core`
2. Increase the Desktop Heap from the default 512, to a value of
       1024 through `regedit`:
       `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
       Manager\SubSystems\Windows`
3. Delete entire workspace of eclipse
4. Reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Websphere MQ 7.0.1.3 does not support Windows 10 operating system
Link to system requirement for MQ 7.0.1.3 : https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27011920

Please install MQ version which supports your operating system (Windows 10).

Comment: So why some of my colleagues could installed this version of MQ on their systems with Windows10-64x